# Is it possible to run a Socket Io and WebRTC server 24*7?

Tags: node.js, socket.io, webrtc

I am trying to build a Video conferencing app with only two users. But, the web app has to run 24*7 with server restart only once or twice a week.

I will be using two raspberry pi with a camera attached. So, can Socket io + WebRTC server run 24*7 or is it not possible?

Answer (score 1):

Webrtc call has no limit over time since is just a collection of protocols for the realtime communication and data transfer. Btw you have to pay attention if the network can change (ex: switching to from a wifi to another one). In that scenario you have to handle the ICE Restart event